# Problem In Microsoft Office 365, web add-in Popup not showing on Ribbon Tab Click

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins, excel-web-addins

I am creating an Excel Web Add-in using JS. I have a tab in my custom ribbon group that says "About." When I click on this tab, a popup window with some information should open. However, my current issue is that I'm not sure how to solve it or accomplish this. Please assist me.

When we click the tab, a popup window will open in the center of the window.

Comment: What code do you use for opening a popup window?

Answer (score 0):

The function that your button runs should call the `displayDialogAsync` method. Here's an example:

```
Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync('https://www.contoso.com/myDialog.html');
```

For more information, see [Use the Office dialog API](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are using the [displayDialogAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.ui?view=common-js-preview#office-office-ui-displaydialogasync-member(1)) function to get the dialog displayed:

```
Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync('https://www.yoursite.com/dialogPage.html', {height: 30, width: 20, displayInIframe: true});
```

For a sample add-in that does this, see [Build Office Add-ins for Excel](https://github.com/OfficeDev/TrainingContent/tree/master/OfficeAddin/02%20Building%20Add-ins%20for%20Microsoft%20Excel). For more samples that use *displayDialogAsync*, see [Code samples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins#code-samples).